# Data conversion from DT_STR to Currency to load with in 2 destinations

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence

I have a data flow task that consists of loading data from a flat file source (Products.csv) to transfer them to:

1. **Staging table:** to save valid data
2. **InvalidRows:** a flat file destination to save invalid data

The data that I need to load are shown in the screenshot.

So, my data conversion component allows to convert 2 attributes: ProductID and Price (as shown in the screenshot).

I'm sure that the result should be as follows:

- **Staging table:** contains the two products where `ID=4` and `ID=6`
- **InvalidRows:** contains the product where `ID=5`

When executing, I get the following result:

> "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>   data."

which is caused by the price column that should be converted from `DT_STR` to `DT_CY`.

It's a conversion problem, and I tried many things (data conversion / derived column), but without success.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the _Truncation_ column to _Redirect Row_?

Comment: yes i tried it , also i changed the output type of the price column in the flat file  source  " products source " : but not solved